# Convert CURL call to C#

Tags: c#, php

I am trying to convert the following PHP cUrl call into c# 4.0 .net code but it is not working properly. My connection is not established and i am not getting result back.
Here is the PHP working code:

```
<?php
    $user = "root";
    $token = "aaaaaa";

        $query = "https://127.0.0.1:2087/json-api/listaccts?api.version=1";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    $header[0] = "Authorization: whm $user:$token";
    echo $header[0];
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_status != 200) {
        echo "[!] Error: " . $http_status . " returned\n";
    } else {
        $json = json_decode($result);
        echo "[+] Current cPanel users on the system:\n";
        foreach ($json->{'data'}->{'acct'} as $userdetails) {
            echo "\t" . $userdetails->{'user'} . "\n";
        }
    }

    curl_close($curl);
?>
```

I did try this code but so far not working

```cs
string user = "root";
string token = "aaaaaa";
string appCallbackURL = "https://127.0.0.1:2087/json-api/listaccts?api.version=1";

HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(appCallbackURL);
webrequest.Method = "POST";
webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization: whm " + user + ":" + token);


var response = webrequest.GetResponse();
```

Can someone help me to convert the PHP code in working c# .net 4.0 code?
Thanks

Comment: I have not tried your code but you must use POST method because you are using POST in C# curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

Comment: i have that: webrequest.Method = "POST";

Comment: Yes that's what i am saying you should use it in PHP also as you have it in C#

Comment: What "doesn't work"? No errors? Having insight into both server and client sides you should be able to debug this further than it seems you have. At a glance would expect SSL *verify* issues. Could test using HTTP to see if that is all.

Comment: PHP code is the one that is working. I remove the POST but still is not working.

Error that i am getting back is:
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

Comment: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format. Error shows on screen

Comment: At a glance, the php code is disabling SSL validation, which you are not doing on the C# side of things

Comment: i did try to disable it with puthing this on top of the code:
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation going forward is to import the curl request into postman and then export it as c#.

In postman you can paste the raw curl and then once it's imported, you'll see a link for 'code' and you can select c#.  It uses the  restsharp package available on nuget.

Comment: I try this and i am getting the following exeption:
"Keep-Alive and Close may not be set using this property.\r\nParameter name: value"
When i remove tha line i get this exeption:
ErrorException = {"Input string was not in a correct format."}